Pygame: Centering a rect after using self.rect.inflate()
So basically I've been tryng to create a small RPG for a school project and have struck a wall when trying to use attacks. I wanted the hitbox for the attack to be bigger than the characters usual hitbox, so I looked around and found rect.inflate() which seems to work. But it only extened in the bottom right corner. So now what I want to do is center it around my character so it has equal distance on all sides. I did try rect.center with another rect which I gave the variables of the first rect before inflatiing it (when it was centered on the character) but that doesn't seem to work. So what I'd like is either a solution to center it, or maybe a better way to do my attacks because for now I just put another animation on top of the non-attacking one.
Any help at all will be appreciated!
P.S The problem most likely lies in the ATK class which is in the end of the sprites code.
Code down below
Main
import pygame
from sprite import *
from config import *
import sys

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('ARCADECLASSIC.TTF', 32)

        self.character_spritesheet = Spritesheet('img/Crusader.png')
        self.terrain_spritesheet = Spritesheet('img/Full.png')
        self.enemy_spritesheet = Spritesheet('img/Goblin1.png')
        self.void_spritesheet = Spritesheet('img/void.png')
        self.intro_background = pygame.image.load('./img/Castle2.jpg')
        self.gameover_background = pygame.image.load('./img/gameover.jpg')

    
    def createTilemap(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(tilemap):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                Ground(self, j, i)
                if column == "B":
                    Block(self, j, i)
                if column == "P":
                    self.player = Player(self, j, i)
                if column == "E":
                    Enemy(self, j, i)
                if column == "V":
                    Void(self, j, i)

    def new(self):
        self.playing = True

        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.blocks = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.player = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.attacks = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

        self.createTilemap()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()


    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.playing = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    Atk(self, self.player.rect.x, self.player.rect.y)
            

    def main(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()        


    def gameover(self):
        text = self.font.render('Quest Failed', True, RED)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(WIN_WIDTH/2, WIN_HEIGHT/2))
        

        restart_button = Button(560, 200, 100, 50, WHITE, BLACK, 'Retry', 32)

        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            sprite.kill()

        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

            if restart_button.is_pressed(mouse_pos, mouse_pressed):
                self.new()
                self.main()

            self.screen.blit(self.gameover_background, (0,0))
            self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)
            self.screen.blit(restart_button.image, restart_button.rect)
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            pygame.display.update



    def intro_screen(self):
        intro = True

        title = self.font.render('Knights Quest', True, BLACK)
        title_rect = title.get_rect(x=10, y=10)

        play_button = Button(560, 200, 100, 50, WHITE, BLACK, 'Play', 32)

        while intro: 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    intro = False
                    self.running = False
            
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

            if play_button.is_pressed(mouse_pos, mouse_pressed):
                intro = False

            self.screen.blit(self.intro_background, (0,0))
            self.screen.blit(title, title_rect)
            self.screen.blit(play_button.image, play_button.rect)
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            pygame.display.update()

g = Game()
g.intro_screen()
g.new()
while g.running:
    g.main()
    g.gameover()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()

sprites
`import pygame
from config import *
import math
import random 

class Spritesheet:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.sheet = pygame.image.load(file).convert()

    def get_sprite(self, x, y, width, height):
        sprite = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        sprite.blit(self.sheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        sprite.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        return sprite
    
    def get_sprite_void(self, x, y, width, height):
        sprite = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        sprite.blit(self.sheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return sprite

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x * SPRITESIZE
        self.y = y * SPRITESIZE
        self.width = SPRITESIZE
        self.height = SPRITESIZE

        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        self.facing = 'down'
        self.animation_loop = 1

        
        self.image = self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (32, 32))


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def update(self):
        self.movement()
        self.animate()
        self.collide_enemy()

        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        self.collide_blocks('x')
        self.rect.y += self.y_change
        self.collide_blocks('y')

        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0

    def movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.x_change -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'left'
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.x -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.x_change += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'right'
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.y += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.y_change -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'up'
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.y -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.y_change += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'down'
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.x_change -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'left'
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.x -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.x_change += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'right'
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.y += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.y_change -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'up'
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.y -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.y_change += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = 'down'
        
    
    def collide_enemy(self):
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.enemies, False)
        if hits: 
            self.kill()
            self.game.playing = False

    def collide_blocks(self, direction):
        if direction == "x":
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.blocks, False)
            if hits:
                if self.x_change > 0:
                    for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                        sprite.rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED
                    self.rect.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width
                if self.x_change < 0:
                    for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                        sprite.rect.x -= PLAYER_SPEED
                    self.rect.x = hits[0].rect.right

        if direction == "y":
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.blocks, False)
            if hits:
                if self.y_change > 0:
                    for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                        sprite.rect.y += PLAYER_SPEED
                    self.rect.y = hits[0].rect.top - self.rect.height
                if self.y_change < 0:
                    for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                        sprite.rect.y -= PLAYER_SPEED
                    self.rect.y = hits[0].rect.bottom


    def animate(self):
        up_animations = [self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(64, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(128, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(192, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(256, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(320, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(384, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(448, 512, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(512, 512, self.width, self.height)]
        
        left_animations=[self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(64, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(128, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(192, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(256, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(320, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(384, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(448, 576, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(512, 576, self.width, self.height)]
        
        down_animations = [self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(64, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(128, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(192, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(256, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(320, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(384, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(448, 640, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(512, 640, self.width, self.height)]

        right_animations =[self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(64, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(128, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(192, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(256, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(320, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(384, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(448, 704, self.width, self.height),
                           self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(512, 704, self.width, self.height),]

        if self.facing == 'down':
            if self.y_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 640, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = down_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

        if self.facing == 'up':
            if self.y_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 512, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = up_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

        if self.facing == 'right':
            if self.x_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 704, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = right_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

        if self.facing == 'left':
            if self.x_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(0, 576, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = left_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

    
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = ENEMY_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.enemies
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x * SPRITESIZE
        self.y = y * SPRITESIZE
        self.width = SPRITESIZE
        self.height = SPRITESIZE

        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0

        self.facing = random.choice(['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'])
        self.animation_loop = 1
        self.movement_loop = 0
        self.max_travel = random.randint(30, 34)

        self.image = self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(38, 1640, self.width, self.height)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (32, 32))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def update(self):
        self.movement()
        self.animate()
        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        self.collide_blocks('x')
        self.rect.y += self.y_change
        self.collide_blocks('y')
        

        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
    
    def collide_blocks(self, direction):
        if direction == "x":
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.blocks, False)
            if hits:
                if self.x_change > 0:
                    self.rect.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width
                if self.x_change < 0:
                    self.rect.x = hits[0].rect.right

        if direction == "y":
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.blocks, False)
            if hits:
                if self.y_change > 0:
                    self.rect.y = hits[0].rect.top - self.rect.height
                if self.y_change < 0:
                    self.rect.y = hits[0].rect.bottom
                
    def movement(self):
        if self.facing == 'left':
            self.x_change -= ENEMY_SPEED
            self.movement_loop -= 1
            if self.movement_loop <= -self.max_travel:
                self.facing = random.choice(['right', 'up', 'down'])

        if self.facing == 'right':
            self.x_change += ENEMY_SPEED
            self.movement_loop += 1
            if self.movement_loop >= self.max_travel:
                self.facing = random.choice(['left', 'up', 'down'])
        
        if self.facing == 'down':
            self.y_change += ENEMY_SPEED
            self.movement_loop -= 1
            if self.movement_loop <= -self.max_travel:
                self.facing = random.choice(['left', 'up', 'right'])
        
        if self.facing == 'up':
            self.y_change -= ENEMY_SPEED 
            self.movement_loop += 1
            if self.movement_loop >= self.max_travel:
                self.facing = random.choice(['right', 'left', 'down'])
    
    def animate(self):
        up_animations = [self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(160, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(288, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(416, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(544, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(672, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(800, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(928, 1376, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(1056, 1376, self.width, self.height)]
        
        left_animations=[self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(160, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(288, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(416, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(544, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(672, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(800, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(928, 1504, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(1056, 1504, self.width, self.height)]
        
        down_animations = [self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(160, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(288, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(416, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(544, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(672, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(800, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(928, 1632, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(1056, 1632, self.width, self.height)]

        right_animations =[self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(160, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(288, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(416, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(544, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(672, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(800, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(928, 1760, self.width, self.height),
                         self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(1056, 1760, self.width, self.height)]
        if self.facing == 'down':
            if self.y_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1632, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = down_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

        if self.facing == 'up':
            if self.y_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1376, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = up_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

        if self.facing == 'right':
            if self.x_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1760, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = right_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1

        if self.facing == 'left':
            if self.x_change == 0:
                self.image = self.game.enemy_spritesheet.get_sprite(32, 1504, self.width, self.height)
            else:
                self.image = left_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                self.animation_loop += 0.2
                if self.animation_loop >= 9:
                    self.animation_loop = 1



class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = BLOCK_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.blocks
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.width = TILESIZE
        self.height = TILESIZE

        self.image = self.game.terrain_spritesheet.get_sprite_void(32, 32, self.width, self.height)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

class Void(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = BLOCK_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.blocks
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.width = TILESIZE
        self.height = TILESIZE

        self.image = self.game.void_spritesheet.get_sprite(190, 120, self.width, self.height)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y


class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = GROUND_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.width = TILESIZE
        self.height = TILESIZE

        self.image = self.game.terrain_spritesheet.get_sprite(64, 64, self.width, self.height)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x 
        self.rect.y = self.y

class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, fg, bg, content, fontsize):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('ARCADECLASSIC.TTF', fontsize)
        self.content = content
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.fg = fg
        self.bg = bg

        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill(self.bg)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.x 
        self.rect.y = self.y

        self.text = self.font.render(self.content, True, self.fg)
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect(center = (self.width/2, self.height/2))
        self.image.blit(self.text, self.text_rect)

    def is_pressed(self, pos, pressed):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pressed[0]:
                return True
            return False
        return False

class Atk(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = ATK_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.attacks
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.width = SPRITESIZE
        self.height = SPRITESIZE

        self.animation_loop = 0

        self.image = self.game.character_spritesheet.get_sprite(38, 1640, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect2 = self.rect
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(256, 256)
        self.rect.center = self.rect2.center
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.collide()

    def collide(self):
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.enemies, True)

    #animate function that i had to remove bc to many characters

        if direction == 'up':
            self.image = up_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
            self.animation_loop += 0.2
            if self.animation_loop >= 6:
                self.kill()
        if direction == 'down':
            self.image = down_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
            self.animation_loop += 0.2
            if self.animation_loop >= 6:
                self.kill()
        if direction == 'left':
            self.image = left_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
            self.animation_loop += 0.2
            if self.animation_loop >= 6:
                self.kill()
        if direction == 'right':
            self.image = right_animations[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
            self.animation_loop += 0.2
            if self.animation_loop >= 6:
                self.kill()`

I have tried this:

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect2 = self.rect
            self.rect = self.rect.inflate(256, 256)
            self.rect.center = self.rect2.center


Which didn't seem to work, but there might have been some sort of trouble by giving both rect the same variables

See the documentation of pygame.Rect.inflate: "Returns a new rectangle with the size changed by the given offset. The rectangle remains centered around its current center. ..." - so what is the problem?

@Rabbid76 Then maybe it's not centered on my character from the beginning. because when I inflate it, only gets wider from the right of my character, and longer from the bottom.
